# JMeter marks the request with response code 429 as failed in the Report and ResultsTree

Tags: jmeter

I am testing rate limiting features of an API.

And I have a JMeter HTTP sampler request, for which the anticipated and actual response code is ***HTTP 429, Too many requests***.

But in the Results Tree and in the generated HTML report, this request's response is marked as failure, even though the actual response is 429 and the Response assertions is also for code 429.

Because of this my overall report is skewed with 100% failures, whereas actually everything has passed.

I need ideas on how to fix this Jmeter reporting issue.

Check the attached screencap of the Response in ResultsTree
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does, all HTTP status codes above 399 and below 500 are so called ["client errors"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses), in general JMeter treats response status codes above 399 as errors.

If status code 409 is something you expect you can configure JMeter to expect it as well, it can be done using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. That was so straight forward. my bad I missed it.

Comment: can you please answer this as well, if possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038560/jmeter-how-to-achieve-different-throughputs-for-different-samplers-under-same