# JMeter - How to achieve different throughputs for different samplers under same thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have three JMeter samplers in a Ultimate Thread Group (20Threads), which have the below throughput requirements.

1. Sampler1 - 2000/min
2. Sampler2 - 250/min
3. Sampler3 - 30/min

And I mentioned the same value in ***Constant Throughput Timer***, but post execution, in the summary report, all the samplers have same throughput around 30-40/min throughput.

How can I achieve the above scenario?

I did try to increase the number of threads to 100 (assuming there are no sufficient threads) and run it but still same results.

And also I tried to change the Throughput Timer to ***Throughput Shaping timer*** but of not use.

And within the ***Constant Throughput Timer*** I tried all the available options of 'Calculate Throughput based on' dropdown. For any option the throughput seems to increase or decrease, but all the samples still have same throughput, but as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to control the throughput of your samplers. For your scenario, you can add **3** Throughput Controllers and configure them as below

1. `Throughput Controller 1` - add `Sampler1` (2000/min) as a child of `Throughput Controller 1` and change throughput value to `88`
2. `Throughput Controller 2` - add `Sampler2` (250/min) as a child of `Throughput Controller 2` and change throughput value to `11`
3. `Throughput Controller 3` - add `Sampler3` (30/min) as a child of `Throughput Controller 1` and change throughput value to `1`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. JMeter threads model assumes that each thread (virtual user) expects previous sampler to finish before starting the next one.

So if you have different throughputs applied to different samplers the overall throughput will be **the slowest one** like any [distributed integrated system](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00607-016-0508-7) acting at the speed of its slowest component.

So the only way of having different throughputs for different samplers is putting them under different Thread Groups. If you need to pass data between thread groups you can use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) functions combination or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)